# Entity framework 6 Lazy loading with db initiation

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, lazy-loading

I am working with EF 6 and Lazy loading.

```
class MainPrograme
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ProgramContext _dbContext = new ProgramContext();

        _dbContext.Programs.Add(new Program
        {
            SecondProgram = new SecondProgram
            {
                Title = "Demo"
            }
        });
        _dbContext.SaveChanges();
        var item = _dbContext.Programs.Find(1);
    }
}
```

Once I disable lazy loading with

```
    Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

It works fine. No relational objects are loaded. `item.SecondProgram`  is `null`. Perfect. However when I delete the database, my db initiation sets up a new db and then lazy loading is not working. If I run the above program again, then lazy loading works fine again. Do you guys have any idea why ? Thanks.

Here is my constructor

```
public ProgramContext()
        : base("Data Source=xxx;")
    {
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        if (!Database.Exists())
        {
            Task.Run(InitializeDatabase).Wait();
        }
    }
```

If database does not exist, InitializeDatabase will setup the db and if I do a db query in the same context instance, lazy loading fails. If I create a new context object and query db via that, lazy loading works.

**Update -**

Below is my full console program. Run it and check SecondProgram property if the item. It is not null. Lazy loading not worked there. Then run the program again without deleting the database and check SecondProgram  property again. Is is null as expected. Why is was not null in the first run ?

```
class MainPrograme
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ProgramContext _dbContext = new ProgramContext();

        _dbContext.Programs.Add(new Program
        {
            SecondProgram = new SecondProgram
            {
                Title = "Demo"
            }
        });
        _dbContext.SaveChanges();
        var item = _dbContext.Programs.Find(1);
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SecondProgram> SecondPrograms { get; set; }
    public virtual SecondProgram SecondProgram { get; set; }
}

public class SecondProgram
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

}

public class ProgramContext : DbContext
{
    public ProgramContext()
        : base("Data Source=XXX;Initial Catalog=MyContainer;Integrated Security=True;")
    {
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }

    public DbSet<Program> Programs { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Could you please add some sample scenarios and output?

Comment: Not quite sure I understand the question, but the `Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled` is context based. So you need to call it for every `DbContext` you do not want lazy loading (everytime you create a DbContext).

Comment: Note that if you never want lazy loading, you can set it to false in the `DbContext` constructor.

Comment: I added my constructor and a bit more of a description in to the original post above. Please take a look at that

Answer (score 1):

Lazy loading can be turned off for all entities in the context by setting a flag on the `Configuration property` as shown below.Please check whether you have done that or not.

example:

```
 public class MyContext : DbContext 
    { 
        public MyContext() //constructor
        { 
            this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false; 
        } 
    }
```

**Note :** You can still Load related entities by using `Eager Loading`

**Update :**

*can you use this :*

```
Database.SetInitializer<ProgramContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<ProgramContext>());
```

*Instead of your code :*

```
 if (!Database.Exists())
    {
      Task.Run(InitializeDatabase).Wait();
    }
```

**Update 2 :**

Your problem here is you haven't used `this` keyword with the `Configuration` property.You have to set it as shown below.

```
 this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

Comment: Thanks for replying.

True. I have done it and is working perfectly. The problem is when db initiation happens. Thats where lazy loading fails. If the InitializeDatabase is running lazy loading is not working. If not, works perfectly. Do you have any idea why ?

Comment: I added my constructor and a bit more of a description in to the original post above. Please take a look at that.

Comment: Please see the `Update` section above.

Comment: use `this` keyword as shown my example above and let us know.

Comment: That works and solves my problem. Whooooo, thanks. 

But isnt 'this' redundant ? Can you explain what exactly happen when I was not using redundant 'this' ?

Comment: The `this` keyword refers to the current instance of the class else no guarantee.

Comment: No, this can't be the issue. Adding `this` would have a function if there is another variable/parameter `Configuration` in scope. Well, that's *highly* unlikely. Note that this other member should also have a `LazyLoadingEnabled` property. It's more likely that this strange parallel call (in a constructor even!) causes unpredictable behavior.

Comment: hope you can accept this answer.here what you said `That works and solves my problem. Whooooo, thanks`.So clearly this is the solution.please accept this and give something back to the community as well. here how to do that : http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: please read this too : `Accepting Answers: How does it work?`http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235

Answer (score 0):

In this case I am checking for the SecondProgram on the same context that I used to create it in the first place. It is already loaded with SecondProgram. Therefore it is not null.

```
ProgramContext _dbContext = new ProgramContext();

    _dbContext.Programs.Add(new Program
    {
        SecondProgram = new SecondProgram
        {
            Title = "Demo"
        }
    });
    _dbContext.SaveChanges();
    var item = _dbContext.Programs.Find(1);
```

When I create a new context object and access Program like

```
ProgramContext _newContext = new ProgramContext();
var item = _newContext.Programs.Find(1);
```

Then we are talking about lazy loding coz it has to load stuff from db. Now it works.SecondProgram is null. Can someone verify this ?

This is not part of a real program. I had this issue when I work with Test cases with NMemory and Effort.